# I'm learning from Python Data Science Handbook and got different graph with same code. What's wrong?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Here is the exact code from the book and output:

```
plt.scatter(data_projected[:, 0], data_projected[:, 1], c=digits.target,
            edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,
            cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('spectral', 10))
plt.colorbar(label='digit label', ticks=range(10))
plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5);
```

Output:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
plt.scatter(data_projected[:, 0], data_projected[:, 1], 
            c=digits.target,
            edgecolor = 'none', alpha= 0.5,
            cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', 10))
plt.colorbar(label='digit label', ticks = range(10))
plt.clim(-0.5, 9.5)
```

Output:

[image]

I guess I need to change something in settings or do something not so complicated but don't know what. Or maybe they changed the dataset?

P.S. I changed color on purpose, it doesn't make any impact on code.

Book chapter:
https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.02-introducing-scikit-learn.html

Comment: The book uses the `'spectral'` colormap. Your code uses the `tab10` colormap. Also, the book uses `sns.set()`, which you don't use here. So the outputs differ.

Comment: Is the graph different? to me it just seems like its been rotated around the y-axis. If that's the case then you need to take a look at your parameters and find what caused this difference.

In addition, I notice you have rewrite the code yourself, I would also just copy and paste the code to troubleshoot this. I understand the value of rewriting code in your own words to learn, I do it as well, but for troubleshooting its best to stick with the original code.

Comment: You probably reversed the sign of the x-axis somewhere.

Comment: Agree, this is the same chart reversed across the y-axis. To know what happened, you would need to compare the steps that generate the underlying data, perhaps a sign was changed somewhere

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest, colormap doesn't affect graph orientation. I also watched for( - ) but didn't find it. So far, Siddarth's explanation looks the most reasonable to me. What's your opinion?

Comment: Well, it's not been mentionned that the issue you inquire about here is the mirroring of the data. "Look different" foremost meant that they look different, independent of the data used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the mirroring, consider that the projection involves an arbitrary choice of basis vectors. I'm in no way a machine-learning expert, so I cannot go into detail about the exact working of the algorithm. But if you run the same code several times, you may get all possible orientations, e.g. for 25 runs:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.manifold import Isomap
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits

digits = load_digits()


fig, axs = plt.subplots(5,5, figsize=(16,9), sharex=True, sharey=True)
for ax in axs.flat:
    iso = Isomap(n_components=2)
    iso.fit(digits.data)
    data_projected = iso.transform(digits.data)
    im = ax.scatter(data_projected[:, 0], data_projected[:, 1], c=digits.target,
                    s=4, 
            edgecolor='none', alpha=0.5,
            norm=plt.Normalize(-.5, 9.5),
            cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('tab10', 10))

fig.colorbar(im, label='digit label', ax=axs, ticks=range(10))


plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, Thanks for catching my mistake in my answer, I had no idea that the projection chooses the orientation arbitrarily. Good catch.